# Functional programming library for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, functional-programming

Is there any functional programming library for Objective-C?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try FunctionalKit

> FunctionalKit is an attempt to use functional paradigms in Objective-C. It is a set of low level functional types & APIs. It contains types such as either, option, etc. that allow your to write correct, clean, tight, succinct and (where possible) typesafe code. It also provides more advanced concepts such as lifting functions into monads.

[FunctionalKit](http://github.com/mogeneration/functionalkit)

Comment: It looks like this actually makes functional-style programming harder than the built-in lambdas and associated methods in 10.6 that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Try out the Blocks branch of FunctionalKit. I've also written a system to automatically wrap any operation in an Option type at runtime, which I'll be releasing soon. Blocks and runtime badassery make FunctionalKit a very useful tool, which I've used extensively in my most recent two iPhone applications.

Answer (score 9):

You could also try out [OCTotallyLazy](https://github.com/stuartervine/OCTotallyLazy), a port of the Java library *[TotallyLazy](http://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/)*.

For example, mapping an NSArray can be done as follows:

```
[array(@"one", @"two", @"three", nil) map:^(NSString *item){
  return [item uppercaseString];
}];

// Returns array(@"ONE", @"TWO", @"THREE", nil)
```

There's also a set of macros available that allow for a shorter syntax, for example:

```
#define TL_LAMBDA_SHORTHAND
[array(@"one", @"two", @"three", nil) map:_([_ uppercaseString])];

// Returns array(@"ONE", @"TWO", @"THREE", nil)
```

It also provides its own collection type, Sequence, which lazily evaluates maps, filters, etc.

Comment: Here's a guide on how to use TotallyLazy: http://intrepidis.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-totallylazy-functional-library.html

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is not a functional programming language (it is quite clearly procedural OO), so I don't see how there would be such a thing. If you're looking for lambdas and concurrency support, that's what Grand Central Dispatch is for in 10.6.

Comment: Pseudo-functional, if you like... I'm looking for something in the spirit of http://functionaljava.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ for Java.

Comment: I take it as a compliment that the only downvotes I get are without accompanying comments.

Comment: Nitpick: Lambdas are not a result of GCD; they are a part of how you use GCD.

Check out FunctionalKit, by the way. It is possible to write clean, mostly functional and typesafe code in Objective-C.

Comment: Functional programming does not need to be done in a "functional programming language". Programming with regard to referential transparency, eschewing side-effects wherever possible is just a discipline that can be used to simplify programming in any language. The more extreme position is that there is no such thing as a functional programming language, only languages who better support functional abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Functional.m](http://github.com/leuchtetgruen/functional.m) for functional programming in Objective-C. It makes heavy use of blocks and contains your usual functional programming suspects, like map, reduce, filter, reject, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [underscore.m](http://underscorem.org).